# whats the error message in my logcat

Tags: android, logcat

I have got this logcat error more then one time. This time I started a new Activity from a non-Activity subclass. The new Activity that starts is empty, so it has nothing with the content to do.

Here are the logcat lines:

```
01-14 11:11:03.562: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-14 11:11:03.702: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.JDL.Apps.Snake/com.JDL.Apps.Snake.SettingsScreen}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.JDL.Apps.Snake.SettingsScreen
01-14 11:11:03.702: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
01-14 11:11:03.702: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
01-14 11:11:03.702: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
01-14 11:11:03.702: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
01-14 11:11:03.702: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-14 11:11:03.702: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-14 11:11:03.702: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
01-14 11:11:03.702: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 11:11:03.702: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-14 11:11:03.702: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
01-14 11:11:03.702: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
01-14 11:11:03.702: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-14 11:11:03.702: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.JDL.Apps.Snake.SettingsScreen
01-14 11:11:03.702: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
01-14 11:11:03.702: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
```

Comment: did you declare the activity in the manifest?

Comment: post your code how your are starting an activity from your class.

Comment: Maggie: Yes I have.

Padma: Easy like this: 
     context.startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.SETTINGS"));

Comment: could you post some more of the code? The error basically means you're trying to say something is one class, when it's not. Specifically, if you do anything with the Activity you're starting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.JDL.Apps.Snake.SettingsScreen 01-14 11:11:03.702: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
```

In short you have a class cast exception.

Comment: it means that you don't have compatible objects to cast or passing  a wrong type of object as a parameter there which is most likely. We need to see that Instrumentation.java line 1021

Comment: you need to provide the code as i wrote it in my previous comment mate.